# Recommended Linux on 32 bit PC

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, 32bit

I have a 32 bit PC with 3 GB RAM and 256 MB graphics memory. I wanted to start learning Linux, but the problem is finding the right distribution. I prefer to use Oracle VirtualBox.

- Ubuntu recently closed 32 bit ISO image.
- Linux Mint Cinnamon is not getting installed.
- Kali Linux is too advanced for beginners.
- Arch Linux, Elementary OS, and Zorin OS are not available in 32 bit format.

So what Linux is advisable for a newbie like me?

Comment: how about [bunsenlabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/installation.html)? Or [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso)

Comment: [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download/) has 32 bit images.

Comment: Are they good. Would they be good for basic learning so that in a year i can advance to kali?

Comment: Yes they are good for basic learning, but it all depends on what you want to learn.

Comment: Fedora still carries 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a 32 bit PC with 3 GB RAM and 256 MB graphics memory. I wanted to start learning Linux, but the problem is finding the right distribution. I prefer to use Oracle VirtualBox.
>
> - Ubuntu recently closed 32 bit ISO image.
> - Linux Mint Cinnamon is not getting installed.
> - Kali Linux is too advanced for beginners.

All three of these distributions have a common base, [Debian](https://www.debian.org).

Per the [documentation](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch03s04.html.en),

> A Pentium 4, 1GHz system is the minimum recommended for a desktop system.

```
| Install Type | RAM (minimum) | RAM (recommended) | Hard Drive   |
| ------------ | ------------- | ----------------- | ------------ |
| No desktop   | 128 megabytes | 512 megabytes     | 2 gigabytes  |
| With Desktop | 256 megabytes | 1 gigabyte        | 10 gigabytes |
```

Answer (score 0):

What distribution are you most comfortable with? Yep, that one.

(Note that today's systems *crawl* with less than 4 GiB RAM... consider a lightweight windows manager for starters)

Comment: Which systems are you referring to?

Comment: @rage, I've got a netbook with 2GiB, can't run Fedora right (64 bit, dual core Atom). My Asus with 4GiB RAM works fine for light work, but can't e.g. compile large packages.